# Does amplify.store return error or catch exception when local storage limit exceeded?

Tags: jquery, amplifyjs

Is there e way to check if local storage limit is exceeded after a call like this:

```
amplify.store("key", object);
```

What happens if i try to store something bigger than the local storage limit ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes , it throws "amplify.store quota exceeded" , as you can see here

```
store.error = function() {
    return "amplify.store quota exceeded"; 
};
```

...

```
try {
                    storage.setItem( key, parsed );
                // quota exceeded
                } catch( error ) {
                    // expire old data and try again
                    store[ storageType ]();
                    try {
                        storage.setItem( key, parsed );
                    } catch( error ) {
                        throw store.error();
                    }
                }
```