# How to check if HTML5 session storage has enough space for storing new item

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I want to store an array of items in html5 session storage.
But before storing new items in array I want to see if there is enough space and if it doesn't has enough I want remove first element and add new item.
How I can know about available space in session storage?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/12508274/1117720

Comment: thank, sorry for duplicate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the data there and catch possible error:

```
try {
    sessionStorage.setItem('key', data);
} catch (e) {
    if (e.name === 'QuotaExceededError') {
        /* do something else */
    }
}
```